# Volume obtained around $y=\sqrt{a}$

Tags: definite-integrals, volume

Let $g$ be a function. $g(x)=\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}$. I want to find the volume of the region obtained rotating around $y=\sqrt{a}$. The picture is:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: What is the domain of $x$? $0\le x\le 4a$?

Comment: I don't know anything. this is all exercise

Answer (score 1):

The distance from the axis of rotation to the curve is $r = 2\sqrt a - \sqrt x$. So a vertical slice of the solid of revolution, of thickness $dx$, will have area $\pi r^2dx = \pi(4a + x - 4\sqrt{ax})dx$. You just have to integrate this expression (over the interval $[0,4a]$, if that is what you want).

Comment: Now, if I rotate this region around $y$ axis, limited by $y=\sqrt{a}$. Thanks!

Comment: Is that a new question?

Comment: yes! It is a new question

Comment: Well, try and do it yourself this time! I've showed you how.

Comment: I tried something. I have changed the limits of integral. I found out $g^-1$